# UWP Toolkit DataGrid remove selected border

Tags: uwp, datagrid

I want to remove datagrid selected cell border. 
I tried many ways but I am not able to remove selected cell border.

Below is my sample code.

```
<Page.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="0"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,10,10"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
    </Style></Page.Resources>

<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
        Height="600" Margin="12" FrozenColumnCount="2"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"  
        AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
        HeadersVisibility="None"
        FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0"
        FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0"
        BorderThickness="1" SelectionMode="Extended" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged"
        >
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="300">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{x:Bind FirstName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LastName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address">
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer">
                            <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{x:Bind Address}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

[Remove selected cell border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amk9i.png)

I have put style for data grid cell and data grid row as well. Please check attached screen shot for sample demo.

Thanks 
I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a peek into the `DataGrid` [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/48e6d7082f8021defdf4393d6318d9001fbb484d/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml#L469), you will see that the cells focus visual is hardcoded:

```
<Grid x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">    
    <Rectangle Stroke="{ThemeResource DataGridCellFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"
               StrokeThickness="2" 
               Fill="Transparent" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               IsHitTestVisible="False"/>    
    <Rectangle Stroke="{ThemeResource DataGridCellFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}" 
               StrokeThickness="1" 
               Fill="Transparent"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               IsHitTestVisible="False" 
               Margin="2"/>
</Grid>
```

And it is using `DataGridCellFocusVisualPrimaryBrush` and `DataGridCellFocusVisualSecondaryBrush` resources. So if you want to change the border, the easiest thing you can do is to override these two resources.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridCellFocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridCellFocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
```

**Note** - focus border is there for a reason - users with keyboard and accessibility devices need it to know what cell is currently focused. If you remove the border completely, it might make the app hard to use for them.

If you want even more control, you can copy the default template and modify it. You can do so by right-clicking the control in **Designer** or **Document Outline**, choosing **Edit additional template** and choosing `DataGridCell`. The select **Create a copy** and that will generate a copy of the default template in your page. Please note you might have to replace `StaticResource` declarations by direct resources (`SolidColorBrush`, etc.)

Comment: Alas, I spent almost 2 days to remove just focus border and finally its done. Thanks Martin.

Actually, I wanted to use grid view control but my requirement is to open details section in each row on clicking of row that I can easily implement with data grid control. Is this possible with grid view control?

Comment: Well, it should be possible if you want to display a popup, or flyout, but expanding an item itself may not be that easy (as you need to expand just one item, not the others)